# Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, linguistics

I do linguistics and I'm looking for a way to enumerate language examples that lets me reference to them in the text.

```
      (1) This is an example.

Sentence \ref{...} provides a good example of basic English.
```

Bonus points if it's usable with `\item`, which makes it easy to use with `org-mode`.

Comment: Related (or maybe duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/repeating-enumerated-list-items-and-their-original-number See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57276/section-based-linguistic-example-numbering-with-brackets

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are good packages for numbering examples in linguistics which have been specifically designed by linguists to meet our needs.  Two of the most commonly used ones are `gb4e` and `linguex`. The questions egreg linked to in the comments show some examples. A third package, ExPex is still in development, and is extremely powerful, although somewhat non-LaTeX like in its syntax.    Here are examples of all three packages which show off some of their abilities.  In the first example, three levels of example embedding are shown.  In the second example, the automatic lining up of glosses for use with examples not in the language of the article you are writing. I've coded the same examples in all three packages to highlight differences in their syntax.

### Overall evaluation

All three packages can very quickly produce standard examples and glosses quite quickly. For most users, and especially new users,  either one of `gb4e` or `linguex` is a good choice. Personally I prefer `gb4e` because it implements true semantic markup of examples using LaTeX environments.  Many `linguex` users prefer it, however, because the source input is simpler (and therefore not semantic at all). Since any good editor can insert chunks of code automatically, this has always struck me as being a weak argument.

I would really only recommend ExPex if you really require the degree of customization that it implements, especially in its handling of complex glossing systems.  For some examples of its capabilities, see [Type a interlinear text, bi or tri-lingual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44050/2693) and [Doing an interlinear text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45858/2693).

### gb4e

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex Wh/Quantifier Interactions\label{WHQ}
\begin{xlist}
\ex[]{What did everyone bring to the party?}
\begin{xlist}
\ex {Beer. \hfill \emph{Individual answer}}
\ex {Bill brought beer, Sue brought wine, Sam brought vodka \hfill \emph{Pair List answer}}
\ex {His favourite drink. \hfill \emph{Functional answer}}
\end{xlist}
\ex[]{Who brought every dish to the party?}
\begin{xlist}
\ex[]{Sue \hfill \emph{Individual answer}}
\ex[*]{Bill brought the salsa, Sue brought the hummus, \\ Sam brought the tabouli \hfill \emph{Pair list answer}}
\ex[*]{Its maker \hfill \emph{Functional answer}}
\end{xlist}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

As we can see in (\ref{WHQ}) there is a subject/object asymmetry in the availability of the Pair list and functional answers.

In example (\ref{citko21}) we can see some data from Polish.
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{citko21} 
\begin{xlist}
\ex[]{\gll Kogo     Jan lubi e      a Maria podziwia e?\\
           who.ACC Jan likes e.ACC and Maria admires e.ACC\\
       \trans `Who does Jan like and Maria admire?'}
\ex[*]{\gll Kogo/Komu Jan lubi e        a Maria ufa e?\\
            who.ACC/DAT Jan likes e.ACC and Maria trusts e.DAT\\
      \trans `Who does Jan like and Maria trust?'}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of gb4e code]

#### Advantages and disadvantages

*Advantages*

- Real semantic markup for examples
- Good support for grammaticality judgements
- Automatic lining up of glosses (same as `linguex`)
- Uses the standard `\label` and `\ref` reference system
- counters are easy to manipulate
- allows for use of `_` and `^` outside of mathmode

*Disadvantages*

- Hard to customize the basic list margins
- allows for use of `_` and `^` outside of mathmode

### linguex

The other commonly used package for linguistic examples is `linguex`.  Here's the same example coded using that package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
\ex. Wh/Quantifier Interactions\label{WHQ}
    \a. What did everyone bring to the party?
        \a. Beer. \hfill \emph{Individual answer}
        \b. Bill brought beer, Sue brought wine, Sam brought vodka \hfill \emph{Pair List answer}
        \b. His favourite drink. \hfill \emph{Functional answer}
    \z.
    \b. Who brought every dish to the party?
        \a. Sue \hfill \emph{Individual answer}
        \b. *Bill brought the salsa, Sue brought the hummus, \\ Sam brought the tabouli \hfill \emph{Pair list answer}
        \b. *Its maker \hfill \emph{Functional answer}

As we can see in \ref{WHQ} there is a subject/object asymmetry in the availability of the Pair list and functional answers.

In example \ref{citko21} we can see some data from Polish.
\ex.\label{citko21} 
  \ag. Kogo     Jan lubi e      a Maria podziwia e?\\
           who.ACC Jan likes e.ACC and Maria admires e.ACC\\
       \trans `Who does Jan like and Maria admire?'
  \bg. *Kogo/Komu Jan lubi e        a Maria ufa e?\\
            who.ACC/DAT Jan likes e.ACC and Maria trusts e.DAT\\
      \trans `Who does Jan like and Maria trust?'

\end{document}
```

#### Advantages and disadvantages

*Advantages*

- Automatic lining up of glosses (same code as `gb4e`)
- Uses the standard `\label` and `\ref` reference system
- shorthands for next and previous examples without using labels
- simple input syntax with contextual determination of levels (at the expense of semantics)
- easy to customize the basic list margins

*Disadvantages*

- markup is not semantic; contextual determination of levels
- some counters are hard coded and hard to modify
- handling of grammaticality judgements needs extra code to extend
- command for glossed examples is different from non-glossed examples
- example groups *must* be separated by a blank line
- cannot be used in conjunction with packages like `xcomment` which allow environments to be selectively excluded/included

[image: output of linguex code]

### ExPex

The [ExPex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package is an extremely powerful package for formatting examples and glosses. It is useable by both Plain TeX and LaTeX. It is highly customizable and supports multiple levels of glossing. It uses a syntax that is more TeX-like than LaTeX like, (for example the basic example environment uses `\ex ... \xe` rather than `\begin{ex} ... \end{ex}` and implements customizations using a syntax based on the PSTricks key-value system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{expex}

% ExPex doesn't implement 3 levels of embedding, so this code is
% required for the first example
\def\beginsubsub{%
\par
\begingroup
\advance\leftskip by 2em
\def\b##1{\par\leavevmode\llap{\hbox to 2em{##1\hfil}}\ignorespaces}}
\def\endsubsub{\par\endgroup}

\gathertags % write tags to external tag file
\Lingset{everygla=\upshape} % make first gloss line upright
\begin{document}
\pex~ Wh/Quantifier Interactions\deftagex{WHQ}
\a {What did everyone bring to the party?}
\beginsubsub
  \b{i.} {Beer. \hfill \emph{Individual answer}}
  \b{ii.} {Bill brought beer, Sue brought wine, Sam brought vodka \hfill \emph{Pair List answer}}
  \b{iii.} {His favourite drink. \hfill \emph{Functional answer}}
\endsubsub
\a {Who brought every dish to the party?}
\beginsubsub
  \b{i.} Sue \hfill \emph{Individual answer}
  \b{ii.} {\ljudge{*}Bill brought the salsa, Sue brought the hummus, \\ Sam brought the tabouli \hfill \emph{Pair list answer}}
  \b{iii.} \ljudge{*}Its maker \hfill \emph{Functional answer}
\endsubsub
\xe
As we can see in (\getref{WHQ}) there is a subject/object asymmetry in the availability of the Pair list and functional answers.

In example (\getref{citko21}) we can see some data from Polish.
\pex<citko21> % an alternative syntax for tagging
\a
\begingl
  \gla Kogo     Jan lubi e      a Maria podziwia e?//
  \glb who.ACC Jan likes e.ACC and Maria admires e.ACC//
  \glft `Who does Jan like and Maria admire?'//
\endgl
\a
\begingl
  \gla Kogo/Komu Jan lubi e        a Maria ufa e?//
  \glb who.ACC/DAT Jan likes e.ACC and Maria trusts e.DAT//
  \glft `Who does Jan like and Maria trust?'//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of expex code]

#### Advantages and Disadvantages

*Advantages*

- extremely customizable using a key/value interface
- support for multiple levels of glossing with very rich formatting
- usable with both Plain TeX and LaTeX
- powerful reference and labeling system but using methods distinct from the standard LaTeX `\label` and `\ref` system
- independent macros for grammaticality judgements

*Disadvantages*

- very idiosyncratic syntax for LaTeX users (although not for Plain TeX users)
- fairly steep learning curve (71 pages of documentation)
- only two levels of automatic embedding

Comment: @doncherry I'll add some more to the answer in a bit, but I don't have time at the moment. I prefer `gb4e` because its markup is semantic and `linguex`'s isn't. With a good editor there's no real reason that the extra code in `gb4e` should pose a problem.  For example, I use TeXShop as an editor and can insert the wrapping code for either a single or multiple example environment into my source with a single keystroke.

Comment: Really nice answer, Alan!

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I think this could turn out to be an extremely helpful resource for every TeXing linguist.

Comment: Does anyone have a good setup for inserting environments for gb4e in AUCTeX/emacs?

Answer (score 8):

You may use the `enumerate` environment with regular `label` and `\ref` combination:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlist{label*=(\arabic*)}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}%%[label*=(\arabic*)]
  \item{This is an example \label{ex:basic}}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:basic} provides a good example of basic English. If you want to continue the numbering, you may use \verb|resume| feature provided by the \verb|enumitem| package.
%
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item{This is an example \label{ex:advanced}}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:advanced} provides a good example of simple English. Hope this is useful.


\end{document}
```

[image]

This won't work if you have some other `enumerate` in the middle. `resume` will try to continue form that point. To have control, you may use `series` option provided by `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label*=(\arabic*),leftmargin=1.5cm,series=example]
  \item{This is an example \label{ex:basic}}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:basic} provides a good example of basic English. If you want to continue the numbering, you may use \verb|resume| feature provided by the \verb|enumitem| package. Some other \verb|enumerate| in the middle:
%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{This is an some other example not related to language \label{ex:other}}
\end{enumerate}
%
And again, one more language example.
\begin{enumerate}[label*=(\arabic*),leftmargin=1.5cm,resume*=example]
  \item{This is an example running very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long into two lines  \label{ex:advanced}}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:advanced} provides a good example of simple English. Hope this is useful.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or define a new list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{example}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[example]{label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=1.5cm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
  \item{This is an example \label{ex:basic}}
\end{example}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:basic} provides a good example of basic English. If you want to continue the numbering, you may use \verb|resume| feature provided by the \verb|enumitem| package. Some other \verb|enumerate| in the middle:
%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{This is an some other example not related to language \label{ex:other}}
\end{enumerate}
%
And again, one more language example.
\begin{example}[resume*]
  \item{This is an example running very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long into two lines  \label{ex:advanced}}
\end{example}

\noindent Sentence~\ref{ex:advanced} provides a good example of simple English. Hope this is useful.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Next step is providing a proper `example` environment. `:-)`

Comment: You could also use a `\newlist` to define your own list environment so you don't need to remember to specify the `resume` option.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own environment `sentence` based on the primitve `list` environment (the environments `itemize` and `enumerate` are based on `list`, amongst others).

I defined

1. an environment `sentence` that can hold exactly one (numbered) sentence. The macro `\item` is used but you don't need to provide it,
2. a macro `\oneSentence` that works just as the environment, and
3. an environment `nsentence` that can hold more than one sentence (you can use it for only one sentence, too, but must insert `\item` explicitly).

Number 1. and 2. has an optional argument that is used as a `\label`, to what you may refer to with `\ref`. In the multiple-sentences environment, you must use `\label` (as you would in an `enumerate` environment).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mySentence}                               % provides the number
\newcounter{myTempSentence}                           % is used for a resume-like style for nsentence
\renewcommand*{\themySentence}{(\arabic{mySentence})}               % (1), (2), (3), …
\newenvironment{sentence}[1][]{
     \begin{list}{\themySentence}{\refstepcounter{mySentence}}\item % \item already provided
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{}=0\else\label{#1}\fi                     % if opt label is provided, use it, otherwise do nothing (needs pdfLaTeX, solutions for other engines are available)
}{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{nsentence}{%
     \setcounter{myTempSentence}{\value{mySentence}} % save old value
     \addtocounter{myTempSentence}{-1}
     \begin{list}{\themySentence}{
         \usecounter{mySentence}
         \setcounter{mySentence}{\value{myTempSentence}}
         \refstepcounter{mySentence}
     }
}{\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\oneSentence}[2][]{\begin{sentence}[#1]#2\end{sentence}}

\begin{document}
Let's take a look at a sentence:
\begin{sentence}[myFirstSentence]
    This is an example.
\end{sentence}
Sentence~\ref{myFirstSentence} provides a good example of basic English.
    \oneSentence[thisIsALabel]{This works, too.}
After sentence~\ref{thisIsALabel} we look at a few more sentences.
\begin{nsentence}
    \item This is another example. \label{mySecondSentence}
    \item And this is a great sentence. \label{exampleForAdvancedEnglish}
\end{nsentence}
Sentences~\ref{mySecondSentence} and~\ref{exampleForAdvancedEnglish} are great examples for advanced English.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]