# Covington Examples Sub-list not lining up

Tags: linguistics, examples, covington

I'm trying to use Covington to generate my examples for my thesis, but anywhere I have sub-examples, the (a) and (b) examples don't line up.

Here is my code: (edited to show min working example, as per request)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\title{The English resultative: Argumenthood status and formal models}
\date{\today}
\author{Elizabeth Christie}
\bibliographystyle{natbib.fullname} % Use this line on Liz's laptop

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in,includefoot,includehead]{geometry} % CARLETON UNI thesis margins
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating} % for making rotated tables
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[citebordercolor=white,linkbordercolor=white,urlbordercolor=white]{hyperref} %for putting links in the document.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage} %puts the page number in the top right corner
\lhead{\rightmark} % puts the section number and name in the top left corner

\avmfont{\sc}
\avmoptions{active}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}
    \item \label{ResBack:Sem:Tel:SubInterval} 
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item Bill heated the mixture hotter.
        \item Bill hammered the metal flatter.
        \item Penelope wove the shawl longer.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}
\bibliography{C:/Bibliographies/lizbib}
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: screenshot of my document]

I want the sub-list to line up with itself, but can't figure out how to do that from what I've read. Can someone please help me?

Comment: It helps those trying to help you if you provide a *full* minimum working example (MWE), beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `covington` at all. It's very old and there are better packages for linguistics example numbering available.  See [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77941/2693).

Comment: I have added more code to make the minimum working example more complete. Hopefully that includes everything that is needed.

Comment: As for the comment by @AlanMunn, I have heard of gb4e, and was hesitant to switch as I would have to change all of the examples in the existing 70 pages of thesis. But, it seems to be better than covington, so I will give it a try. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, covington 1.2 (August 2016) introduced a length `examplenumbersep` that can be used to manually fix such things, e.g. `\setlength\examplenumbersep{1em}`