# Referring to a tikzpicture, but no label shown

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, labels

I'm trying to refer to a tree in the document. The tree has a label and in the text it is referred to as 2.2, but the label 2.2 is not shown next to the tree. The code including the packages I use is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
       \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]\label{reactiontreeABEPQ}
        \matrix (tree) [%
          matrix of nodes,
          minimum size=1cm,
          column sep=2.5cm,
          row sep=1cm,
        ]
        {
              &  $\EA$ &  \\
            &    $\EB$ & $\EAB$ \\
               $E$ & & \\
               & $\EP$ & $\EPQ$  \\
               &  $\EQ$ & \\
        };
        \draw[<->] (tree-1-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+A}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+B}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+P}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+Q}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-1-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+B}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+A}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+Q}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+P}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \ref{reactiontreeABEPQ}
\end{document}
```

This code above is the tree I would like to label in the document. However, the label is not shown next to the tree. Does it have to do with the size of the tree or can `tikzpictures` maybe not be labeled?

Comment: Can't you just put the thing in a `figure` environment, add a caption and move the label there? Then you can refer to it as figure.

Comment: @marmot Putting the tree in a figure environment, like inbetween     '\begin{figure}...\end{figure}', doesn't work for me. Also, I have trouble creating a code block in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how labels work. A `\label` command (roughly) simply picks up the value of the most recent `\refstepcounter` command, writes its value to the `.aux` file. Since the  `tikzpicture` environment doesn't contain an instance of `\refstepcounter`, when you issue a `\label` command next to a `tikzpicture` it will pick of the last value of the most recent element in your document that contains an instance of `\refstepcounter`.  For example, in the following document, the `\label` command will end up with the value `1.1`, because that's the output of the value of the the counter for `\subsection`.  If you comment out the `\subsection` command, and recompile (twice) the label will change to `1`, the value of the `\section` counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{tikzpicture}\label{mynode}
\node at (0,0) [draw,red] {A node};
\end{tikzpicture}
This is the label value: \ref{mynode}
\end{document}
```

So if you want to label and number your trees, you need to put them into some kind of environment that has its own numbering system, such as an equation, or a figure, or some other type of example numbering system. Then the placement of the counter will be specified (in an equation it's on the left or right; in the case of a `figure` it's in the caption, etc.)

So you need to decide how these trees are supposed to be numbered and then use `\label` and `\ref` with respect to those elements. You can't attach a label to a `tikzpicture` by itself.

For example, here's a version of your diagram using the `equation` environment to number it.  Since all your nodes seem to be math nodes, I've changed the code to be `matrix of math nodes` which removes the need to wrap each node in `$`. You might also want to investigate the `tikz-cd` package which can draw similar types of diagrams with less work, I suspect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\foreach \x in {A,B,P,Q,AB,PQ} {% This code defines all the commands you didn't define in your example
\expandafter\xdef\csname E\x\endcsname{\text{E\x}}} % it should be removed in your actual code
\begin{document}
\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{tikzpicture}\label{mynode}
\node at (0,0) [draw,red] {A node};
\end{tikzpicture}

Here label value is \ref{mynode} because it gets the number of the most recent subsection.
\begin{equation}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped,baseline]\label{reactiontreeABEPQ}
        \matrix (tree) [%
          matrix of math nodes,
          minimum size=1cm,
          column sep=2.5cm,
          row sep=1cm,
        ]
        {
              &  \EA &  \\
              &  \EB & \EAB \\
            E & & \\
              & \EP & \EPQ  \\
              &  \EQ & \\
        };
        \draw[<->] (tree-1-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+A}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+B}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+P}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-3-1) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+Q}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-1-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+B}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+A}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {$\xrightarrow{+Q}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {$\xrightarrow{+P}$};
        \draw[<->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

Here the label value is \ref{reactiontreeABEPQ} because  it references the equation numbering.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

See the following question for some more detail:

- [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/2693)

As an example of a system for numbering arbitrary objects, you could use one of the linguistics example numbering packages such as `gb4e`.  You can see this in action with trees in the second link below.

- [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/2693)
- [How to add a numbered label to syntax tree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226797/2693)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and including the examples!