# Covington examples and chapter numbers

Tags: numbering, chapters

I'm trying to use `covington` examples across multiple chapters. This defaults to giving me chapter numbers - that is, the first example in chapter 2 is (2.1). I added:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

to eliminate the chapter numbers, but this just gives me (.1) instead of (2.1).  Is there a way to remove the chapter numbering portion in `covington`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the minimal document that shows your issue. Not everybody (including me) is familiar with `covington`.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}` since equation is the counter that is used in the example environment

Comment: Don't use `covington`. Use `gb4e` or `linguex` instead. Or if you have sophisticated glossing needs use `expex`. See [Numbered examples in linguistics I can refer back to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/2693)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want your equations numbered from chapter to chapter Christian's solution may or may not work for you. By default, the `book` class resets the `equation` counter at each chapter. If you want sequentially numbered examples throughout the whole document independent of chapter, you can do the following instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{example}
An example
\end{example}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{example}
An example
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I would still recommend using another package for example formatting, however, since `covington` is really quite limited.  See:

- [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/2693).

Answer (score 1):

The `covington` package uses the `equation` counter for numbering examples.

Since `theequation` defaults to `\thechapter.\arabic{equation}` for a `book` - like class removing the `\thechapter` part from `\theequation` is not sufficiently done with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}`, which would be a bad idea anyway since chapters would not appear numbered at all.

The `\theequation` macro must be redefined:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
```

in order to 'kill' the chapter number glued to the example number.