# How to make covington glossed examples not italic?

Tags: lyx, linguistics, covington

I'm using glosses in LyX and this makes the first line italic by different. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a minimal example of LaTeX code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Not much info is provided to explain the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `covington` package uses a version of the `gloss` macros developed by Marcel van der Goot, which also for the basis for the `cgloss4e` package used by other linguistics example packages.  The following macros are defined to set the font for the first, second or third lines of a `\gll` or `\glll` set.

```
\eachwordone
\eachwordtwo
\eachwordthree
```

So to make the first line non-italic you can add the following to the preamble:

```
\let\eachwordone\normalfont
```

To do this in LyX you go to Document Settings -> LaTeX Preamble.  Make sure you add it after the `covington` package is loaded.

There are also other example numbering packages available, which depending on your needs might be better.

- [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/2693)

Comment: Thank you! is it also possible to define an indentation of the third line? I have not been able to to do this by inserting /indent latex code, thin spaces etc.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of `covington` 2.0, the above can also be done via

```
\renewcommand*\glosslineone{\normalfont}
```

Indentation of the third (translation) line could be done with

```
\let\saveglt\glt
\def\glt{\saveglt\hspace*{1em}}
```

or, if you use the new macro `\glot` of `covington` 2.0 rather than `\glt`:

```
\renewcommand*\glosslinetrans[1]{\hspace*{1em}\covenquote{#1}}
```

(adjust the length `1em` to your needs)

Note that with LyX, you'd need to embrace all this in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` in the preamble, since covington is loaded after the user preamble.