# How do I cross-reference example sentences in text?

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to include some numbered example sentences in my report, like in this paper (introduction and throughout the paper): https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/8471/file/Wiegand_et_al_Inducing_a_Lexicon_of_Abusive_Words_2018.pdf

From the blue text of the references to the examples they seem to be labeled somehow. Does anyone know how they might have done this, or know a good solution for this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/35864 might be helpful

Comment: @moewe awesome, thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great! I voted to close this question as a duplicate. If you have any issues getting a solution to work, please don't hesitate to ask a new question.