# Linguistics Example Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I am currently working with the gb4e package for linguistics in LaTeX, and I am wondering if there is an easy way to align parts across examples. For instance, in the following example, I want to left align "bar" with "something else."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex \begin{xlist}
        \ex foo: bar
        \ex something: something else
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would a table work for you?

Comment: @Davislor There are various packages designed just for this.

Comment: Maybe I read your question too fast. The regular glossing macros are for within an example not across them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numbered examples in linguistics that I can refer back to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77937/numbered-examples-in-linguistics-that-i-can-refer-back-to)

Comment: Close voters, this is NOT a duplicate of the linked question. It's asking to do something that the standard packages cannot do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a handy package called `listliketab` which allows you to create tabular material that looks like a list. This can be used to do what you want quite easily.  The `listliketab` package allows you to store the formatting properties of a list and then creates a tabular column type `L` for the label of the list.  This column type gets used as the first column within a regular tabular. For an enumerated list like the `xlist` environment of `gb4e` you also need to set up a counter for the label.  I've done this by creating a `tabexe` environment and a `\tbex` macro to increment and output the counter.  Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\newcounter{tabex}
\renewcommand{\thetabex}{\alph{tabex}}
\storestyleof{xlista} % this stores the formatting of the sublist
\newcommand{\tbex}{\refstepcounter{tabex}\thetabex.}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tabexe}{\setlength{\llt@bot@sep}{0pt}\setcounter{tabex}{0}%
\begin{listliketab}}{\end{listliketab}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{tabexe}
\begin{tabular}[t]{Lll} % make sure you add [t] to align with the main example number
\tbex & something & foo\\
\tbex & foo & something
\end{tabular}
\end{tabexe}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]